# HTTPS with Elastic Beanstalk Subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been using Heroku and they provide SSL for their herokuapp.com subdomains.

Is it possible to have HTTPS with EB's subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't** add ssl directly into the domain owned by AWS, such as default domains for EB environments.

However, you can a **CloudFront** (CF) distribution to front your EB. The CF provides SSL certificates and HTTPs:

- [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html)

The alternative is to use **your own domain**. Then you can use HTTPs listener on your load balancer in the EB environment. The easiest way to achieve that would be through Route53 and ACM:

- [Routing traffic to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html)
- [Configuring HTTPS for your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html)

Comment: I am assuming CF will connect to EB using HTTP? but then is that secure and not the same as using HTTP directly with EB?

Comment: That's correct. If you want full SSL, then you have to have your own domain, because you can register SSL certificates only on domains that you control. Also CF [does not allow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html) self-signed certfs: " You cannot use a self-signed certificate for HTTPS communication between CloudFront and your origin. "

Comment: I already use a custom domain with HTTPS but if you look up the host of the custom domain, the CNAME points to the EB domain. Since I am using HTTPS with a certificate for my custom domain, when you go to the EB domain, it shows a security certificate warning which I want to avoid

Comment: Did you load your ssl certificate on your ALB?

Comment: Yes, I did add a listener for HTTPS with the certificate from my custom domain on my ALB

Comment: If you don't mind, I think it would be better to post new question with the details of your domain, alb and ssl setup, and error messages. Its difficult to imaging all these settings based on the comments, and also would allow others to provide help.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this really matters since I don't intend users to access the site with the EB domain

Comment: @Anatol You can add redirection rule to the ALB to redirect any request using EB url to your custom domain.